# Highcharts exporting button as Download button in exporting.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

I want to have Exporting menuitem button as Download button as it was in previous version of exporting.js.

What changes to make in exporting.js to achieve it. 
I am not creating custom button as i need the same download button throughout the app wherever i have highcharts.

Answer (score 0):

We have a compatibility module for the old Highcharts 2 look.

```
<script src="https://rawgit.com/highcharts/highcharts/master/js/modules/exporting-old-look.src.js"></script>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/a4syLsgf/.

Comment: But i am using export-csv along with it for CSV export. And that throws an error.  So i dont want it to be backward compatible rather i just need Download button instead of menuitem button

Comment: You need to define menuItems to CSV / XLS. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/n3c97c66/